# Can we add more nodes in parameter codegenConfigurationNodes of create_job() using boto3 for AWS Glue visual job?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-glue

I'm trying to create job using aws cli for creating glue visual job using create_job() from boto3. For creating visual job in glue for which we need to pass the parameter CodeGenConfigurationNode in create_job(). I am getting an error something like this when I pass multiple node into the CodeGenConfigurationNode parameter:

**raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInputException: An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateJob

operation: More than one node was specified. Exactly one node must be specified for CodeGenConfigurationNode**

I'm passing json file data to the CodeGenConfigurationNode parameter:

```
glue_client.create_job(
                Name='test', Description=description, Role=role_arn,
                Command={'Name': 'glueetl', 'ScriptLocation': script_location, 'PythonVersion': '3'},
                GlueVersion='4.0', CodeGenConfigurationNodes=codeGenConfigurationNodes)
```